# Selecting specific columns with specific values pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a data frame of 30 columns and I want to filter it for values found in 10 of those columns and return all the rows that match.  In the example below, I want to search for values equal to 1 in all df columns that end with "good..."

```
df[df[[i for i in df.columns if i.endswith('good')]].isin([1])]

df[df[[i for i in df.columns if i.endswith('good')]] == 1]
```

Both of these work to find those columns but everything that does not match appears as NaN.  My question is how can I query specific columns for specific values and have **all** the rows that don't match not appear as NaN?

Comment: use .any(1) instead of .isin([1])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter columns first with [`str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html), select columns by `[]` and compare by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html). Last add [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for at least one `1` per row

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.endswith('good')]
df1 = df[df[cols].eq(1).any(axis=1)]
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[1,1,4,5,5,1],
                   'C good':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D good':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E good':[5,3,6,9,2,1],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A  B  C good  D good  E good  F
0  a  1       7       1       5  a
1  b  1       8       3       3  a
2  c  4       9       5       6  a
3  d  5       4       7       9  b
4  e  5       2       1       2  b
5  f  1       3       0       1  b

cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.endswith('good')]

print (df[cols].eq(1))
   C good  D good  E good
0   False    True   False
1   False   False   False
2   False   False   False
3   False   False   False
4   False    True   False
5   False   False    True

df1 = df[df[cols].eq(1).any(1)]
print (df1)
   A  B  C good  D good  E good  F
0  a  1       7       1       5  a
4  e  5       2       1       2  b
5  f  1       3       0       1  b
```

You solution was really close, only add [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df1 = df[df[[i for i in df.columns if i.endswith('good')]].isin([1]).any(axis=1)]
print (df1)
   A  B  C good  D good  E good  F
0  a  1       7       1       5  a
4  e  5       2       1       2  b
5  f  1       3       0       1  b
```

EDIT:

If need only `1` and all another rows and columns remove:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.endswith('good')]
df2 = df1.loc[df1.eq(1).any(1), df1.eq(1).any(0)]
print (df2)
   D good  E good
0       1       5
4       1       2
5       0       1
```